# Нужна ли запятая после слова «понятия»? Если нужна, то почему

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, уточнения

*Объектом исследования в данной работе являются пословицы, включающие в себя оба понятия(,) «война» и «мир», или одно из этих понятий.*

Comment: Елена, повтор слова лучше убрать: *...или одно из них.*

Comment: И повтор слова можно не убирать. Я, будучи носителем, вижу такой повтор грамматически идеальным, а значит, люди массово так пишут, а значит, это не какая-то грамматическая ошибка.

Answer (score 3):

После первого ответа и комментариев под ним, решил дать своё понимание этой темы.

Предупредительной интонации, при которой ставится двоеточие, нет. Здесь имеет место уточнение.

> Обособляются (выделяются запятыми, реже – тире) слова и словосочетания, уточняющие смысл предшествующих слов (уточнение – это переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому).
> <...>
> Уточняющие определения могут конкретизировать общее значение местоимений ***этот, тот, такой, каждый, один*** (в значении местоимения) и т. п.

К «и т. п.», считаю, относится и местоимение «оба».

**Ответ:** запятая нужна.

*Объектом исследования в данной работе являются пословицы, включающие в себя оба понятия, «война» и «мир», или одно из этих понятий.*
(Ударение падает на «оба» и на «одно».)

**Заметка:** повтор слова лучше убрать: *...или одно из них.*

**Источник:** [Уточняющие члены предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118) (справочник Розенталя).

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Использование слова «оба» говорит о том, что эти понятия уже упоминались. И здесь мы вновь ссылаемся на них, повторяем, причём со вставочной интонацией. Их можно даже выделить тире:
*Объектом исследования в данной работе являются пословицы, включающие в себя оба понятия – «война» и «мир» – или одно из них.*

Без слова «оба», конечно, запятые не требуются.

**Дополнение** после комментария Rumpelstilstkin (орфография и пунктуация сохранены): «Вы посмотрите на предложении. Оно начинает абзац, где рассказывается о чём будет исследование. Там текст выглядит так: есть исследование, а исследование будет вот об этом». (Правда, пока я писал это дополнение, ошибки были исправлены. Хорошо.)

Если это самое начало текста об исследовании и понятия ещё не вводились, то необходимо убрать слово «оба» перед ними:
*Объектом исследования в данной работе являются пословицы, включающие в себя понятия «война» и «мир» – либо оба, либо одно из них.*

О!Только что дошло, что **изначальное предложение стилистически**, по-моему, **не совсем корректно**. Если понятия уже вводились, то следует добавить ещё одно «или»/«либо»:
*Объектом исследования в данной работе являются пословицы, включающие в себя или оба понятия («война» и «мир»), или одно из них.*
*Объектом исследования в данной работе являются пословицы, включающие в себя либо оба эти понятия, либо одно из них.*

**Дополнение** после ответов Sharon

Согласен с тем, что достаточно одного союза «или» (вчера что-то не туда «дошло»).
А также с тем, что «предложение казалось странным — что-то в нем не сходилось…». И вот не сходилось, по моему мнению, именно то, что не хватало знака после сочетания «оба понятия».
Об **особом случае** для пары понятий «война и мир» (вместе взятых в кавычки) надо бы спросить у автора вопроса. У меня в голове такая структура не помещается.
Елена, к сожалению, вообще никак не реагирует и не отмечает стрелочками полезные ответы.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146789/discussion-on-answer-by--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 3):

*Объектом исследования в данной работе являются пословицы, включающие в себя **оба понятия «война» и «мир» или одно из них.***

1. Думаю, что  слово «оба» подразумевает здесь **парное употребление** обоих слов, когда в конкретной пословице они сравниваются или противопоставляются, тогда смысл будет такой: *Объектом исследования в данной работе являются пословицы, включающие в себя **пару понятий** «война» и «мир» или одно из этих понятий.*
2. Я бы все-таки **оставила** союз «***или***», так как вариант «***или…или***» имеет  **определенные особенности**, о чем можно прочитать  в грамматике:  [http://rusgram.ru/Сочинительные_союзы#2](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8B#2)

**Союз «или»:** каждая из этих двух ситуаций возможна, но не обязательна.

**Союз «или…или»:** (1) подчеркивается, что каждый конъюнкт участвует в сочинении; (2) каждый конъюнкт рассматривается отдельно.

В предложении с союзом ***или…или*** подчеркивается, что в выборе из нескольких альтернатив, выражаемом данным союзом, участвует каждый конъюнкт. Такой акцент **оправдан,** например, в случае, когда других альтернатив, кроме упоминаемых, нет. Поэтому типичным для или…или является **контекст** «третьего не дано».

3. Возможный вариант: *Объектом исследования в данной работе являются пословицы, включающие в себя **оба понятия «война и мир» или одно из них.***

Comment: Sharon, с одним "или" могу согласиться, хотя не совсем понятно "третьего не дано". Там же получается, что будут представлены пословицы с обоими понятиями или с одним, то есть третьего варианта как раз и нет. А вот насчёт необособления самих понятий – никак не ожидал, что вы считаете это правильным.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin Не беспокойтесь, пожалуйста, я напишу сейчас неправильный ответ. А то непорядок...

Answer (score 0):

Это тема [обобщающие слова перед однородными членами](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103). Если после обобщающего слова не следует предупредительная интонация, то двоеточие не ставится. Вот пример из справочника Розенталя:

> Писатели-классики Гоголь, Тургенев, Чехов рисовали картины из жизни крестьян.

Если есть предупредительная интонация, то запятая ставится. Предыдущий пример можно переделать, чтобы показать это:

> Картины из жизни крестьян рисовали следующие писатели-классики: Гоголь, Тургенев, Чехов.

В вашем предложении нет предупредительной интонации, поэтому двоеточие не ставится. Перед ‟или” запятая не ставится, если только это не присоединение и там нет соответствующей присоединительной интонации. В итоге:

> Объектом исследования в данной работе являются пословицы, включающие в себя оба понятия "война" и "мир" или одно из этих понятий.

Чтобы лучше было понятно, что такое предупредительная интонация, лучше привести одинаковое предложение с ней и без неё:

> Картины из жизни крестьян рисовали писатели-классики: Гоголь, Тургенев, Чехов. (Есть предупредительная интонация.)
>
> Картины из жизни крестьян рисовали писатели-классики Гоголь, Тургенев, Чехов. (Нет предупредительной интонации.)

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Если при двух однородных, связанных союзом ‟и”, первое однородное распространённое, то пауза перед ‟и” более длинная, чем если бы однородное было нераспространённым, взгляните на примеры: ‟Я увидел необычную вазу и странного человека, державшего её” и ‟Я увидел огромного размера необычную вазу и странного человека, державшего её. Обратите внимание, что такая более длинная пауза не обозначается запятой. Я думаю, что часть участников форума тупит здесь потому, что они видят эту более длинную паузу и ошибочно решают, что пауза перед ‟или” – это вторая пауза от отступления, как при уточнении или пояснении.

Comment: Если бы не было слова "оба", то да, можно без знаков: *включающие в себя понятия "война" и "мир" или одно из этих понятий*. А так, без знака, даже звучит не по-русски.

Comment: Без какого знака?

Comment: Любого. После "оба понятия".

Comment: Там нет предупредительной интонации. Сравните: ‟Пословица включает в себя следующие слова: война и мир”. Может быть вас смущает длинная пауза перед ‟обе”, но так всегда, когда одно однородное распространённое. Например: ‟Я увидел огроменного размера необычную вазу и странного человека, державшего её”

Comment: Нет, дело не в интонации, хотя она здесь тоже играет роль, а в структуре. Видите, вы добавляете слово "следующие". У нас "оба". Это всё меняет. Без этих слов можно без двоеточия: *Пословица включает в себя слова "война" и "мир”*.

Comment: Это обычные однородные – ‟оба понятия” или ‟одно понятие”. Это обычные однородные дополнения.

Comment: Есть отчётливые правила про однородные с неповторяющимся союзом и про отсутствие двоеточия при отсутствии предупредительной интонации. Эти правила более чем отчётливы. Не надо здесь ничего придумывать, это очень простая ситуация.

Comment: Простая, да с изюминкой, её видеть, слышать и понимать надо.

Comment: Не любое слово делает интонацию предупредительной. В данном случае ‟оба” не делает её предупредительной.

Comment: Да при чём здесь предупреждение? Пишем: *оба понятия или одно понятие*. Вклиниваем уточнения, пояснения, названия: *"оба понятия (война и мир) или одно", "оба понятия, война и мир, или одно", "оба понятия – война и мир – или одно"*.

Comment: Это не пояснения, это род-вид отношения (не совсем, но когда что-то обозначается более общим словом, а потом раскрывается, термин ‟род-вид” подходит больше всего). Дерево берёза, мечта стать столяром, бригадир Зырянский, понятия ‟война” и ‟мир”, писатели-классики Гоголь и Тургенев. При род-вид отношениях нет интонации отступления, как при пояснении.

Comment: Вот. Вы опять пишете без слов, значимых для структуры, интонации и смысла. Добавьте "следующие" или "оба" и всё, привет. Напишете так? *Оба бригадира Зырянский и Кошкин, оба дерева берёза и осина, следующие писатели Гоголь и Тургенев*. Нет. // Я закончил.

Comment: Сперва вы говорили, что тут интонация отступления, как при уточнении, а теперь бросились обратно – защищать предупредительную интонацию. Что вы привели примеры без предложений. Приведите их в предложении, тогда и поговорим.

Comment: Предупредительная интонация координально отличается. Её прямо невозможно не заметить. Посмотрите на пример из справочника Розенталя без её: ‟Славятся своими здравницами города-курорты Кисловодск, Железноводск, Ессентуки, Пятигорск (ср.: …следующие города-курорты: …)”. Даже в таком предложении может не быть предупредительной интонации. Вы просто спорите, потому что никогда не задумывались над этим, видимо, потому что спутать предупредительную интонацию и не предупредительную очень сложно, если вы обращали внимание на это.

Comment: К тому же когда есть два однородных в середине предложения. С предупредительной интонацией вряд ли вообще существуют такие предложения.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к ответу Rumpelstilskin .Запятая перед обобщающем словом не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Пояснение к первому ответу

*Объектом исследования в данной работе являются пословицы, включающие в себя **оба понятия «война» и «мир»** *или* **одно из  них**.*

1. Интересно, что сначала я была **согласна с мнением Александра**.  Считала, что здесь уточнение и обдумывала вопрос о замене союза.

Вот типичная ситуация **для уточняющего значения:**

*Три сестры Володи, Катя, Соня и Маша — самой старшей из них было одиннадцать лет, — сидели за столом и не отрывали глаз от нового знакомого. ... **И обе старшие девочки, Катя и Соня,** стали зорко следить за мальчиками* (А.П. Чехов «Мальчики»).

Девочки уже названы в предыдущем тексте, а потом упоминаются в предложении в сочетании со словом «обе» (и та и другая).

2. Я полагала, что **у нас такая же ситуация**, но предложение казалось странным — что-то в нем не сходилось… И тогда я предположила, что *оба понятия «война» и «мир»* это *связанная пара слов «война и мир»*, то есть **особый случай** для слова «оба».
3. Отметим особо, что значение здесь **определительное**, поэтому нет запятой. Уточнения в данном частном случае нет, и уж никак **нет никакого обобщающего слова**, ну и предупредительной интонации тоже нет.

И здесь хотелось бы услышать пояснение ситуации у Сержа, утверждающего, что «запятая перед обобщающим словом не нужна». Кстати, у Розенталя чеховский пример дан в теме уточняющих слов, а не в теме обобщающего слова перед однородным рядом. Да и однородный ряд — это всего лишь пара членов ряда, связанных союзом И (читается как одна фраза).

4. **О союзах.**  Союз «или» имеет значение, **достаточное** для данного сообщения. Нет необходимости использовать союз или…или и что-либо **подчёркивать**. В любом случае  нужную семантику определяет автор.

**P.S. Еще одна попытка** записать "странное" предложение:

*Объектом исследования в данной работе являются пословицы, включающие в себя понятия «война» и «мир» (**оба или одно из них**).*

Comment: А здесь есть обобщающие слова: ‟Писатели-классики Гоголь, Тургенев, Чехов рисовали картины из жизни крестьян”? Если да, то почему в сочетании ‟оба понятия война и мир” сочетание ‟оба понятия” не обобщающее слово (сочетание), и прямо ‟никак нет никакого”? Мне интересно узнать эту чудесную логику. И Серж там просто имел ввиду, что после обобщающего слова.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin К сожалению, это долго объяснять, а у меня мало времени. Пожалуйста, задайте эти вопросы на форуме.

Comment: А здесь есть обобщающие слова: ‟Писатели-классики Гоголь, Тургенев, Чехов рисовали картины из жизни крестьян”? Это простой вопрос. Да или нет? Напишите одно слово.

Comment: Если простой, то подумайте сами, а для меня он сложный, извините еще раз.

Comment: У вас были какие-то соображения, на основании которых вы написали ‟никак нет никакого обобщающего слова”. Я задал вам вопрос, вы пошли и посмотрели, что в справочнике Розенталя прямо об этом предложении говорится, что там обобщающее слово, вы поняли, что если вот это обобщающее слово, то и ‟оба понятия” – обобщающее слово (сочетание), потом поняли, что влипли со своим ‟никак нет никакого” и теперь выкручиваетесь.

Comment: Пошла-таки посмотреть справочник Розенталя, надо же выкрутиться:  4. Если однородным членам предложения, выраженным собственными именами лиц,  ПРЕДШЕСТВУЕТ ОБЩЕЕ ДЛЯ НИХ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ, НЕ ВЫСТУПАЮЩЕЕ В РОЛИ ОБОБЩАЮЩЕГО СЛОВА (при чтении в этом случае отсутствует характерная для произнесения обобщающего слова пауза), то двоеточие перед ними не ставится: Писатели-классики Гоголь, Тургенев, Чехов рисовали картины из жизни крестьян. Обратите внимание на частицу НЕ. Спокойной вам ночи.

Comment: Да, моя вина. Там написано, что если нет предупредительной паузы, то это не считается обобщающим словом. Это довольно тупо, но так был выстроен этот термин.